# Convert dictionary of dictionary into jsonObject to send as RequestBody swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I am trying to convert a Dictionary that has an array of dictionary inside it to Json Object which as a JsonArray of JsonObject inside it to send a request but I always get an error stating:

"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSURL)'"

Ive tried converting it through:

```
 requestBody = ["audio": finalMap]
 let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: 
   requestBody)

-----This is the Dictionary -------
      [
   "audio": [
     [
      "__type":, "filename": , 
      "content":data1.wav,
      "speech": {
                 "__type" =;
                  flags = 3;
                  grammar = "in";
                 languageCode = "en-US";
                 name = pin;
               }, 
      "name": ], 
       [
      "__type":, "filename": , 
      "content":data2.wav,
      "speech": {
                 "__type" =;
                  flags = 3;
                  grammar = "in";
                 languageCode = "en-US";
                 name = pin;
               }, 
      "name": ],
      [
      "__type":, "filename": , 
      "content":data3.wav,
      "speech": {
                 "__type" =;
                  flags = 3;
                  grammar = "in";
                 languageCode = "en-US";
                 name = pin;
               }, 
      "name": ],,
    ]
 ]
```

-----This is the expected result-------

```
{
  "audio": [
{
  "__type": "SpeechVerifierAudio",
  "name": "string",
  "filename": "string",
  "content": "string",
  "speech": [
    {
      "__type": "SpeechContext",
      "name": "string",
      "grammar": "string",
      "languageCode": "string",
      "phrases": [
        "string"
      ],
      "flags": 0
    }
  ]
}
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your issue is that you have an NSUrl in your dictionary, can't you convert it to a URL ?

(URL are encodable while NSUrl are not)

Comment: Well, I had the audio file in the URL form, but when I did  Data(contentsOf: audioFile), then it worked. I would love to know why though.

Comment: to convert a dictionary to JSON (or plist) content of the dictionary must be Encodable, that is to say the key is String, the value is of one of those kind: String, Int, Double, Date,Data, URL or of a custom type conforming to Encodable protocol

Comment: the link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types